# What is this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

[image: Game Coloriud]

I found this game and I'm very curious for know about of algorithm implemented in it.
I don't know how look for this, I don't know what is this algorithm and I want study it.

This is the game http://www.rustylake.com/puzzle-and-skill-games/coloruid.html

Really Thank you.

Comment: Some kind of fractal noise.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a basic ["Flood Fill" algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

It's performed on custom 'pixels', but the principle seems the same.